# Remove the line of box

Tags: plotting, graphics, graphics3d, boxes

Just wondering, is it possible to remove certain 'line' of the box?

```
Show[Graphics3D[{Text[Style["x"], {3, -4.4, 1.1}], 
Text[Style["z"], {5, -4.4, .5}], 
Text[Style["y"], {5.33, -0.32, .15}]}], BoxRatios -> {.8, .6, .2}, 
ViewPoint -> {1.5, 1, .8}, ImageSize -> 52 8]
```

Comment: Are you looking for the option `Boxed->False`? If you still want axes you can add both, `Boxed->False,Axes->True`.

Comment: Putting 'Boxed-> False' will erase all of the box's line. Is there any other way to remove let say only one line of the box? @N.J.Evans

Answer (score 1):

I would use graphics primitives and `ImageScaled` to roll my own. To get you started, here's a quick example, though it's not very flexible, or elegant.

```
topBox[] := {
   Line[{ImageScaled /@ {{0, 0, 1}, {1, 0, 1}}}],
   Line[{ImageScaled /@ {{0, 0, 1}, {0, 1, 1}}}],
   Line[{ImageScaled /@ {{1, 0, 1}, {1, 1, 1}}}],
   Line[{ImageScaled /@ {{0, 1, 1}, {1, 1, 1}}}]
   };
bottomBox[] := {
   Line[{ImageScaled /@ {{0, 0, 0}, {1, 0, 0}}}],
   Line[{ImageScaled /@ {{0, 0, 0}, {0, 1, 0}}}],
   Line[{ImageScaled /@ {{1, 0, 0}, {1, 1, 0}}}],
   Line[{ImageScaled /@ {{0, 1, 0}, {1, 1, 0}}}]
   };
uprights[] := {
  Line[{ImageScaled /@ {{0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 1}}}],
  Line[{ImageScaled /@ {{1, 0, 0}, {1, 0, 1}}}],
  Line[{ImageScaled /@ {{1, 1, 0}, {1, 1, 1}}}],
  Line[{ImageScaled /@ {{0, 1, 0}, {0, 1, 1}}}],
  }

Show[
 Graphics3D[{
   Text[Style["x"], {3, -4.4, 1.1}],
   Text[Style["z"], {5, -4.4, .5}],
   Text[Style["y"], {5.33, -0.32, .15}],
   Red,
   bottomBox[],
   Blue,
   uprights[],
   Green,
   topBox[]
   }],
 BoxRatios -> {.8, .6, .2},
 ViewPoint -> {1.5, 1, .8},
 ImageSize -> 52 8
 , Boxed -> False
 ]
```

Which will produce:
[image]

Then it's up to you to decide which lines you want to plot.